# Stripping Data from Excel Columns (Like Python Strip())

Tags: excel, strip, delimited

I'm trying to strip (or extract data) from columns in Excel. I'm not a power-user, although have done exactly what I want to do now in Python before but can't do so this time...

```
""slip""=>""20.0300006866455""       ""depth""=>""8.30000019073486""
```

Above are two sample columns, I want to remove everything except the numbers. As I said, I know you can do so using the strip() function in Python but after a bit of googling - doesn't look like I can do the same in VBA? I have tried Text-Column by delimiter and it is too messy. Any tips would be appreciated, I'm fully aware the answer is probably simple...

Cheers!

Comment: Did you try to specify characters you want to remove as an argument to strip function, `'""8.30000019073486""'.strip('"')` => `8.30000019073486`

Comment: Python yeah that's fine - but I'm stuck in Excel here. Not ideal!

Comment: How did the quotes get there? If this happened by opening a CSV file in Excel, you can avoid it by adjusting the import settings. (If you are more than a beginner in Python, you could very quickly write a converter that reads csv, with the correct import settings, and writes xlsx.)

Comment: just how the information is delivered unfortunately. I've actually made a little converter that does that, but the mess of the dataset is making me favour a more visual solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to remove those quotes inside the cell?
Do all the cells have same formatting? If so you could just select the entire column, then use find and replace option of excel to change as you want:
Find : ""
Replace with : (leave it empty)

Click replace all --

This will do your need in seconds.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Good idea, if it suffices to remove the quote character `"` everywhere in the column this is definitely the simplest solution.

Comment: I want to remove everything other than the number, but same technique and I've got a result. Thanks!!